# Simply the HTML below?

Tags: html, css

Another question on making the code efficient, I was wondering how to achieve this?, please note I want to achieve the results same as below, just want to really simplify it, and struggling to to this.

```html
<div>
    <span style="letter-spacing:normal">
    <span style="orphans:2">
    <span style="text-transform:none">
    <span style="white-space:normal">
    <span style="widows:2">
    <span style="word-spacing:0px">
    <span style="text-decoration-style:initial">
    <span style="text-decoration-color:initial">
    <b style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><span style="font-size:10.5pt"><span style="font-family:Wingdings"><span style="color:#005ad2">«</span></span></span></b><b style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><span style="font-size:10.5pt"><span style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI Semilight&quot;, sans-serif"><span style="color:#005ad2">&nbsp;Feedback&nbsp;</span></span></span></b><b style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, sans-serif; font-size:12pt"><span style="font-size:10.5pt"><span style="font-family:Wingdings"><span style="color:#005ad2">«</span></span></span></b></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What IDE are you using that created such a mess of markup? This is almost impossible to read

Comment: @esqew it was from Outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've guessed already most of this is largely unnecessary. After some analysis you can farm out most styles to the parent `<div>` element and apply classes to the child `<span>` tags as you need to:

```css
div {
  letter-spacing: normal;
  orphans: 2;
  text-transform: none;
  white-space: normal;
  widows: 2;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.5pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005ad2;
  text-decoration-style: initial;
  text-decoration-color: initial;
}

span.icon {
  font-family: "Wingdings";
}

span.text {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="icon">«</span>
  <span class="text">&nbsp;Feedback&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="icon">«</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I know what you're going for. Try making your styles like this instead of calling span all the time, just call it once. like this:

```
<style>
span {
  letter-spacing:normal;
  orphans:2;
  text-transform:none;
  white-space:normal;
  widows:2;
  word-spacing:0px;
  text-decoration-style:initial;
  text-decoration-color:initial;
}
</style>
```